# Segfaulting while finding path through maze

Tags: c, maze

I am trying to print out the coordinates of the maze as I am trying to solve using depth first search algorithm, however, it prints out the initial position, but it seg faults. Is there something I am doing wrong??? Here is my code :

```
#include "mazegen.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#define  BUFFERSIZE 500
#define  FLAG 

void mazeSolution(char maze[100][100], int counter, int counter2)
{
   stack*currentCell;

   int i;
   int j;

   currentCell = create();

  for(i=0; i<counter; i++)
  {
      for(j=0; j<counter2; j++)
      {

          if(maze[i][j] == 'S')
          {
              push(currentCell,i,j);
              currentCell->visited = true;
          }

      }
  }

   printStack(currentCell);

   while(currentCell != NULL)
   { 
      pop(currentCell);

      if(maze[i][j] == 'F')
      {
           break;
      }
      if(i != 0)
      { 
          if(maze[i-1][j] == ' ' && currentCell->visited != true)
          {
              currentCell->visited = true;
              push(currentCell,i-1,j);

          }
      }
      if(maze[i+1][j] == ' ' && currentCell->visited != true)
      {
          currentCell->visited = true;
          push(currentCell,i+1,j);
      }
      if(j != 0)
      {
          if(maze[i][j-1] == ' ' && currentCell->visited != true)
          {
              currentCell->visited = true;
              push(currentCell, i,j-1);
          }
      }
      if(maze[i][j+1] == ' ' && currentCell->visited != true)
      {
           currentCell->visited = true;
            push(currentCell, i, j+1); 
      }

 }

  printf("No solution\n");


  printStack(currentCell);

}
```

I think it has something to do with my pop function and with the way I have implemented it

```
void pop (stack*theStack)
{
    node*theHead;

    if(theStack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Stack. Error\n");
         exit(0);
    }

    theHead = removeFromFront(theStack->list);

    theStack->list = theHead;


}
node*removeFromFront(node*theList) 
{
    node*temp;

    temp = theList->next;

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("pop Error\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    theList = theList->next;

    return theList;
}.
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? In which line it is generating segfault?

Comment: I have and I commented out the if statements and so it prints out the first node, then it goes through an error and then it sefgaults right after that

Comment: show us the code of the `pop` function

Comment: You never seem to check whether i+1 or j+1 are valid ?

Comment: You define BUFFERSIZE but do not show its use. You suggest problem is in pop function, buf you do not show its implementation. How you imagine we we help you, shall we guess your whole code? BTW, maze size 100 by 100 makes from 2,5 thousand to 10 thousand cells, depending on the maze representation. Are you sure 500-items buffer will suffice?

Comment: Posted my pop and getFromFront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping a *visited* status on the stack is useless - you need to check if the specific position has been visited when you try to access it from some new direction, which may happen if there is a loop in your maze. So the proper place for this attribute is a maze itself, not a stack.

You don't need separate `stack` and `node` structures - the stack is actually a list of nodes.

Building a stack is quite easy, but you need to imagine it's structure and behaviour **before** you start encoding. There are two basic (plain C) solutions: use a pre-allocated array or dynamically linked list. Let's use an array.

A stack's item will be

```
typedef struct node {
    int i, j;
} Node;
```

a stack itself:

```
Node stack[ 10001];
```

and a number of items currently stacked:

```
int stkptr = 0;
```

Now we can test if the stack contains any data:

```
int StackNonEmpty() { return stkptr; }
```

push new position onto the stack:

```
void Push(int i, int j) {
    stack[ stkptr].i = i;
    stack[ stkptr].j = j;
    stkptr ++;
}
```

read a position from the stack's top (assuming `StackNonEmpty() != 0`):

```
void Fetch(int *pi, int *pj) {
    *pi = stack[ stkptr - 1].i;
    *pj = stack[ stkptr - 1].j;
}
```

and remove it from the stack:

```
void Pop() { stkptr --; }
```

We also need to define a marker for visited positions:

```
int VISITED = '.';
```

or

```
#define VISITED '.'
```

and we're ready to write the algorithm:

```
for(i=0; i<counter; i++)
    for(j=0; j<counter2; j++)
        if(maze[i][j] == 'S')
        {
            Push(i,j);   // set the Start position
            i = counter; // this is to break the outer loop
            break;       // and this breaks the inner loop
        }
while( StackNonEmpty())
{
    Fetch(& i, & j);             // get a current position
    if( maze[i,j] == 'F')              // Finish found?
        break;
    if( maze[i,j] == ' ')              // empty cell?
        maze[i,j] = VISITED;
    // find next possible step
    if( i > 0 && maze[i-1,j] == ' ')   // cell to the left is empty
        Push(i-1,j);                   // step left
    else
    if( j > 0 && maze[i,j-1] == ' ')   // cell above is empty
        Push(i,j-1);                   // step up
    else
    if( i+1 < counter && maze[i+1,j] == ' ')
        Push(i+1,j);                   // step right
    else
    if( j+1 < counter2 && maze[i,j+1] == ' ')
        Push(i,j+1);                   // step down
    else                               // dead end - no way out
        Pop();                         // step back
}
if( StackNonEmpty())      // exited with break, so 'F' found
    PrintStack();
else
    PrintFailureMessage();  // could not reach 'F'
```

To show the results just print all items of the `stack` array until the `stkptr` position:

```
void PrintStack() {
    for(i = 0; i < stkptr; i ++)
        printf( "%d,%d\n", stack[i].i, stack[i].j);
}
```

**EDIT**
'VALID' status assignment corrected (was == instead of =), `PrintFailureError` replaced with `PrintFailureMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this portion of your code:

```
while(currentCell != NULL)
{ 
      pop(currentCell);

      if(maze[i][j] == 'F')
      {
           break;
      }
   ...
}
```

You are popping a value from the stack - this is ok. But you need to assign the popped value to`i` and `j`. In your code, the value of `i` and `j` remain unchanged, so you have an infinite `while` loop. You are continuously pushing values in the stack inside this loop, which ultimately leads to segfault.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. How would I assign it ??

Comment: @user3712556 modify your `pop` function so that it assigns `i` and `j` the value which is at the top of the stack. One possible solution would be to pass `i` and `j` as parameters of the pop function (`void pop (stack* theStack, int* i, int* j)`).

Comment: I tried that and it does not work, it's still segfaulting. This is what I did. void pop (stack*theStack, int x, int y)
{
    node*theHead;
        
    if(theStack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty Stack. Error\n");
         exit(0);
    }
   
    theHead = removeFromFront(theStack->list, x, y);
    
    theStack->list = theHead;

   
}

Comment: 1. You need to assign `i` and `j` to their appropriate values (which is the top values of the stack)
2. You need to pass them by reference, not by value

Comment: What I do not understand, is that if we pop the first position of the maze, there will be nothing in the stack and that is why it is segfaulting. I saw this logic online and I applied it, but I don't seem to properly understand the poping of the first node?

Comment: You need to assign the values *before* you pop the top of the head